# How to "lock" an input based on another input

Tags: switching

I'm trying to control a lot of devices using a microcontroller, and I need to control them faster than a shift register can move data. So, I want to make 'groups' of devices that I can switch between, change output values, and quickly switch away from.

This is the basic idea: I want a circuit with 2 inputs -- A and B, and one output -- C. 'A' is the 'latch' pin, and 'B' is the 'data' pin.

- If A is low, I want C (output) to stay the same regardless of B.
- If A is high, I want C (output) to be the same as B.

Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: google `D latch`

Comment: my favourite is hc137

Comment: If you gave us more details about your circuit we might be able to come up with an alternative solution.

Comment: How fast do you wish to switch them? To be faster than a switch register suggests extremely high speeds.  Fully descriobing what you wish to do helps us help you better.

Comment: @jsotola A D latch seems to be exactly what I need here, is there a good DIP IC that can handle ~5vdc with multiple latches in it that you know of for me to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A D-Latch ended up being the best option. I'm probably going to use the SN74HC373N or CD4042BE IC, just because it has many latches in one package. It will depend on what voltage I end up needing.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand right, maybe like this:

A high pass B to output

A low pass C to output

[image]

Or with latched C (you can add another inputs to SR using ORs):

[image]

Comment: What is the block on the right with 'SQR' inside it in the second part of your answer?

Comment: @drobot  SR flip-flop (not clocked), it holds the value on Q output until you change it with SR inputs, so A,B signals.

Answer (score 0):

> and I need to control them faster than a shift register can move data

You can control shift registers at several tens of MHz, the real problem is probably your code or the microcontroller you are using.

At these speeds, if it's not fast enough for your application, then you are getting into FPGAs.

You can also use logic buffers with a parallel bus.

> Is there a simple way to do this?

You can use hardware logic as Michal answered, but since you have a microcontroller, you'd rather optimize that side and do the logic in software.

Answer (score 0):

> So, I want to make 'groups' of devices that I can switch between, change output values, and quickly switch away from.

Here's an idea on how to cut down on the BOM...

There are shift registers which contain output latches like the '595.

To make sure they don't change when shifting out new data all you need to do is to disable the clock signal on that shift register.

So the idea is...

- use one GPIO pin for the data out signal and this goes to all of the shift register chains
- use one GPIO pin for the shift clock signal
- use GPIO pin for each shift register chain; each of these goes into an AND gate with the shift clock signal and then on the chain's shift clock signal
- use GPIO pin for the '595 latch clock; this one signal goes to all of the shift register chains

Alternatively, if you didn't want to use the AND gates you could use a different GPIO pin for the clock signal on each shift register chain.